# Haskell function composition -- putStrLn . show

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

So I've got two functions that based on their types, I feel like I should be able to combine with function composition.

```
ghci> :t show  
show :: Show a => a -> String  
ghci> :t putStrLn  
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

An initial attempt was successful,

```
ghci> ( putStrLn . show ) "Hello World!"  
"Hello World!"
```

I figured I'd try defining a new function as that composition

```
ghci> let myShow = putStrLn . show
```

But it didn't work:

```
ghci> myShow "Hello World!"  

<interactive>:28:8:  
    Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[Char]'  
    In the first argument of `myShow', namely `"Hello World!"'  
    In the expression: myShow "Hello World!"  
    In an equation for `it': it = myShow "Hello World!"
```

Interestingly, the type of my `myShow` function became `() -> IO ()`

```
ghci> :t myShow   
myShow :: () -> IO ()
```

I had assumed that the type would have been `Show a => a -> IO ()` .

Does anyone know why this attempt at function composition failed?

(I realize that this is probably a pretty basic question, but I'm just getting started with the language, so bear with me here)

Comment: You've done nothing wrong as a beginner. The dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) didn't like the type variable `a` (that you inferred correctly) and filled in the unit type.

Comment: Also a beginner in Haskell, why did it work for me? In GHCi `:t myShow` returned `myShow :: Show a => a -> IO ()`

Comment: Ah, believe it was because I had previously done `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`. Although, I would have thought that would reset when I quit GHCi.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the link

Comment: @name It might be due you and martin using different versions of GHC -- the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default in GHCi (but not elsewhere) since GHC 7.8.1.

Comment: @duplode Thanks! On version 8.0.1, so that must be it.

Comment: By the way `putStrLn . show` is what `print` does.